# symfony2 form multiple select with arraycollection

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, arraycollection, multipleselection

I would like to create a form to edit my users.
Users and roles connected with **ManyToMany**.
In UserUsers entity I have a $roles variable which is `ArrayCollection`:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

On my form I would like to add roles to my users via multiple select form element.
In my user form:

```
public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {
    $builder->add( 'username' )
            ->add( 'password', 'repeated', array( 
                    'type' => 'password',
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'first_options' => array( 
                            'label' => 'Password' ),
                    'second_options' => array( 
                            'label' => 'Repeat Password' ) ) )
            ->add( 'roles', 'choice', array( 
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'multiple' => true ) );
}
```

Now my multiple select is empty.

If I turn mapped to true, I got an error message:

> UserRoles could not be converted to int in...

I've tried a lots of ways, but I could not solve this problem correctly.

Comment: What type do you have in your $roles ArrayCollection?

Comment: All elements in $roles ArrayCollection is an entity (UserRoles).

Comment: For a choice of entities you should use the special choice field type 'entity' (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).  For an example see my answer to a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519961/symfony-2-form-create-user-and-add-group/13521462#13521462

Comment: Okay, I changed roles like this:
`$builder->add( 'roles', 'entity', array( 
                          'class' => 'AcmeUserBundle:UserRoles',
                          'multiple' => true,
                          'property' => 'name' ) );`
Then I got an error message:
Expected argument of type **"Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection", "array" given**

Comment: That's odd, as ArrayCollection implements Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection. Is it possible that roles() is reassigned to an array elsewhere? Or that ArrayCollection is not resolving to the doctrine class?

Comment: I fould the problem. In UserUsers entity I have this:
` public function getRoles() {
  return $this->roles
     ->toArray();
 }`
Here I convert the roles to array, because in my loginController I have to pass the roles as array:
`$token = new UsernamePasswordToken( $user, $user->getPassword(), 'admin_area', $user->getRoles());`
If I remove the toArray() method in UserUsers getRoles getter, and modify loginController like this:
`$token = new UsernamePasswordToken( $user, $user->getPassword(), 'admin_area', $user->getRoles()->toArray());`
Then I have an error message everywhere:

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\wamp\www\admin\symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider.php on line 95 and defined in C:\wamp\www\admin\symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken.php line 34

Comment: Is this now the same issue as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200507/role-interface-and-manage-roles?

Comment: Yes, it is and I did just the same in UserUsers entity:
` public function getRoles() {
  return $this->roles
     ->toArray();
 }

 public function getRolesAsObject() {
  return $this->roles;
 }`

Now it is working:
`$builder->add( 'rolesAsObject', 'entity', array( 
      'label' => 'roles',
      'class' => 'AcmeUserBundle:UserRoles',
      'multiple' => true,
      'property' => 'name' ) );`
BUT :)
As you can see, my property is the name of the role which is a number, because it is a language key id. Can I call a function on this property somehow?

Comment: This sounds like a separate issue - i.e. is it that you need a translated value for the role name? If so I suggest create another question.

Comment: okay, i made a new question about this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479052/symfony2-translate-form-entity-property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a choice of entities you should use the special choice field type 'entity' (see Symfony manual for [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)). For an example see my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519961/symfony-2-form-create-user-and-add-group/13521462#13521462).
If you get further errors you may also find this question on [Role Interface and Manage Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200507/role-interface-and-manage-roles) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

for the fosuserbundle I do it like that:

```
        $builder->add('roles', 'choice', array(
        'multiple' => true,
        'choices' => array(
            'ROLE_USER' => 'User',
            'ROLE_AUTHOR' => 'Autor',
            'ROLE_MODERATOR' => 'Moderator',
            'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin'
        ),
        'label' => 'Rollen',
        'required' => true
    ));
```

Comment: This would be good, but I store the roles in the database and when I open the users to edit, I want to be selected those roles which are assigned to the current user.

Comment: I have already understood and I strongly recommend the use of FOSUserBundle - Because of the security. There you can store multiple roles to a user. This is the end what you want.