# Symfony2 translate form entity property

Tags: forms, symfony, properties, entity, translate

I have a symfony2 form for edit users. My users has roles and you can select multiple roles for one user.

In my form I display the UserRoles entity:

`$builder->add( 'rolesAsObject', 'entity', array(
                        'label' => 'roles',
                        'class' => 'AcmeUserBundle:UserRoles',
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'property' => 'name' ) );`

This works correctly, but the name property is just a number, an id for a language key, because I would like to translate the name of the roles.

Is this possible to call a function somehow on the property?

Comment: are you using Symfony translations in files / stored in the db or have you created your own translation mechanism?

Comment: I'm storing translations in database with my own translation mechanism. This is a service which needs a language key which can be string, int or object. Here I would like to give int to this service. This int is in the 'name' property.